# Ignore s3_host_alias in paperclip conditionally?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip, amazon-cloudfront

We use cloudfront for our images hosted on s3 through paperclip; however it has some aggressive caching and we have part of our code that *needs* fresh data (some image manipulation).

Is there any way of overriding `s3_host_alias` on calling the url?

Everything I've found so far regarding this topic talks about *adding* cloudfront, not about ignoring it; and even then, everything is systemwide.

Our paperclip config:

```
# Paperclip Config
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/bin/"
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  storage: :s3,
  s3_protocol: :https,
  url: ':s3_alias_url',
  default_url: "https://#{SETTINGS['s3']['bucket']}.s3.amazonaws.com/missing/:class/:attachment/:style.png",
  s3_host_alias: SETTINGS['s3']['cdn_url'],
  s3_credentials: {
    bucket:            SETTINGS['s3']['bucket'],
    access_key_id:     SETTINGS['s3']['access_key_id'],
    secret_access_key: SETTINGS['s3']['secret_access_key']
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be dirty but you can try this.

```
#set the value in your controller
Photo.my_custom_attr  = "My custom value"

#In your model
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
    cattr_accessor  :my_custom_attr

    Paperclip.interpolates :my_custom_attr do |attachment, style|
        Photo.my_custom_attr
    end 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same need so I did some digging through the paperclip code and  here's what I found:

The s3 storage module has still registered the interpolation you're looking for, it just isn't used when you call `#url` on the attachment since you probably have set something like `url: ':s3_alias_url'` set in your call to `has_attached_file`. So, what you can do is use the Paperclip interpolator manually by calling [interpolate](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/paperclip/Paperclip%2FInterpolations.interpolate).

For example:

`Paperclip::Interpolations.interpolate(':s3_path_url', User.first.avatar, :original)`

You can also substitute the other interpolations the s3 module defines for `':s3_path_url'`, e.g. `':s3_domain_url'`.